# Unable to lock orientation on iPad Air 2

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, orientation, ios9

The iOS application I am working on has a view that needs to be locked in landscape orientation.  Up to this point, that was accomplished by using the `shouldAutorotate` and `supportedInterfaceOrientations` methods, but on an `iPad Air 2` running `iOS9 beta5`, these methods never fire and the orientation is not locked.

I have tried on the following devices, methods fired on all except the Air2 (running debug with Xcode beta6):
iPhone 6+, iPad Mini, iPad Air 2, iPad 2, iPad 3

The methods not firing are as follows:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    return YES;
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientationMask)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeRight;
}
```

View controller is displayed via `presentViewController`

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Multitasking can be turned off by adding the `UIRequiresFullScreen` field to the application's info.plist with the boolean value `YES`, and this will allow the orientation delegate methods `shouldAutorotate`, `preferredInterfaceOrientation`, and `supportedInterfaceOrientations` to fire.

As far as locking orientation **AND** supporting multitasking, I have not found a way to do this.

Answer (score 5):

The 'Requires full screen' setting can be enabled from 'General' of the target settings.

[image: Requires full screen]

With this enabled, the orientation code will now run. As mentioned by ackerman91, you can also set `UIRequiresFullScreen` boolean to YES in the application info.plist or in the target 'Info' tab.

Answer (score 0):

I am thinking this is collateral damage with the multi-tasking feature.
You won't be able to assume anymore that you own the whole screen.
There may be other methods to call to disallow the multi-tasking mode.