# iOS 9 orientation issues lock in iPad Air

Tags: ios, ipad

I am facing a problem with orientation lock issue in iPad Air after I upgraded it to iOS 9.

I have NavigationController which is locked to orientation Landscape. Using the following methods.

```
    - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: (UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft);
}

- (BOOL) shouldAutorotate
{
    return NO;
}

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}
```

I have already changed  `UIRequiresFullScreen` to `YES` but, is there any other work around other than blocking multitasking

Ref: [Unable to lock orientation on iPad Air 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32359775/unable-to-lock-orientation-on-ipad-air-2)

Answer (score 0):

Multitasking *requires* that your app be able to adopt any orientation at any time. You *cannot* lock your navigation controller to landscape only and be multitasking-compatible. Therefore you must get rid of one or the other: either remove the landscape-only restriction or continue to use UIRequiresFullScreen.

Comment: Can we restrict full screen to certain screens and make it available to other screens?