# Lock UIViewController orientation on iPad

Tags: ios, swift, ipad

Is exist any way to lock screen orientation for one of `UIViewControllers` in iPad application without selecting `Requires full screen`?

I know that `Requires full screen` is for iPad multitasking mechanism. Tell me if it is true. I must choose between multitasking and locking one of the screens? Can I have both of these things?

Comment: In my experience you can't prevent rotation on iPad while also supporting multitasking.

Comment: hi @dan, any clue from apple's documents about this?

Comment: I found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32359775/unable-to-lock-orientation-on-ipad-air-2), and thanks for the hint!

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I am struggling with this for two days now.

Answer (score 0):

[Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bqpc3.png)
In General info of your app Deselect both landscape modes and select only portrait mode

By Default all apps are any orientation compatible. You can choose orientation in General > Deployment info.

Comment: Look on my question. I want to lock one of the screen for Portrait rest of them should work in every orientation.

Answer (score 0):

Why not implementing

```
override var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.portrait
}
```

in the UIViewController that should stay in e.g. portrait mode.

Or do

```
override var shouldAutorotate: Bool {
   return false
}
```

You might want to do that in your surrounding UINavigationController though.

Comment: When `Requires full screen` is unchecked it doesn't work.