# Support split view and control iPad orientation at the same time

Tags: ios, swift, ipad

I want to disable rotation on a certain UIViewController in iPad, yet at the same time retain split view in the app.

I am aware that we can check 'Requires full screen' in the General tab to trigger the delegate methods `supportedInterfaceOrientations`, `shouldAutoRotation` etc to be called, and I can toggle the rotation here.

But I realized that once I check this, split view is no longer supported in the app. Is there a way to keep split view and control the orientation in certain UIViewControllers at the same time?

Comment: "Requires full screen" has nothing to do with orientation. It means that you don't support iPad multitasking.

Comment: Do you want that UIViewController to never rotate and only be in one orientation e.g. the view controller is only landscape even though the device is portrait.

Comment: I don't want the UIViewController to rotate only in the onboarding view, but I want the rotation to be enabled in all other cases. And this can be done in `supportedInterfaceOrientations`.

Comment: @rmaddy "Requires full screen" will allow the orientation delegate methods to fire if I'm not wrong https://stackoverflow.com/a/32363363/7766218

Comment: You shouldn't be dealing with rotation events in modern iOS. Just worry about size and trait changes (see the related UIViewController methods).

Comment: @hopeweaver, have you found a solution to your (and mine!) problem?