# How can I enable split view and control the screen orientation?

Tags: swift, xcode

Somebody else [asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48194721/support-split-view-and-control-ipad-orientation-at-the-same-time) the same question in 2018, but he/she did not get answer so hopefully I will have more chance. :-)

Basically, I need my app to have the split view enabled. To do so the target deployment info should be:

- All the 'Device orientation' selected
- The 'Requires full screen' not selected

To have the possibility to control the orientation, you need the target deployment information to be:

- The 'Device orientation' needs at least 'Portrait' OR 'Portrait + Landscape left + Landscape right'
- The 'Require full screen' needs or does not need to be selected.

Like you can see, I did not put the 'Upside Down' option from 'Device Orientation' because doing so, I can't lock the orientation for a specific view controller.

If you think it is possible, what am I missing?

Here the code that I am using to lock the orientation based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67684405/4321277):

AppOrientationUtility

```
struct AppOrientationUtility {
    static func lockOrientation(_ orientation: UIInterfaceOrientationMask) {
        if let delegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate {
            delegate.orientationLock = orientation
        }
    }

    static func lockOrientation(_ orientation: UIInterfaceOrientationMask, andRotateTo rotateOrientation: UIInterfaceOrientation) {
        self.lockOrientation(orientation)
        UIDevice.current.setValue(rotateOrientation.rawValue, forKey: "orientation")
    }
}
```

And using it:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    AppOrientationUtility.lockOrientation(UIInterfaceOrientationMask.portrait, andRotateTo: UIInterfaceOrientation.portrait)
}
```

Comment: First, consider the basics of iOS and iPadOS. (You didn't specify anything, but orientation really doesn't apply to macOS.) iOS? There's no such thing as "split screen". All apps are full screen, period. iPadOS? It's "split screen" *only* when multi-tasking and/or showing multiple windows of your app - and then it's only two windows at a time. So now that me and you are on the same page, what is it about using a `UISplitViewController` (preferable in iOS/iPadOS 13+) that falls short of your needs?

Comment: @dfd, you are right, I should mention that I was talking about iPadOS. I will check for UISplitViewController that I was not aware of, but I did not want to add any new view controller to my app to handle that and let the OS does the trick for me. Thanks for the suggestion.